# Opening a subdirectory to read its contents

Tags: php, loops, directory

I have a directory structure that looks like this, with my script sitting in the 'alerts' directory:

[image]

Each directory in the 'subscribers' directory has config files that I want to read, however, I am having a hard time opening the sub directory within 'subscribers'. For instance, I cannot seem to open the 'MNTF' directory.

Below is a quick script I wrote, am I missing something?

```
if($sub_handle = opendir('subscribers/')){
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($sub_handle))) {
        if (substr($entry, 0, 1) == '.') {          
            continue;
        }   


        if($handle = opendir($entry)){      
            echo "in my second directory";
        }
        else{
            exit('cannot read subscriber');
        }        
    }
}
else{
    exit('nope');
}
```

When I echo out `$entry`, it reads `MNTF`. The output on the screen is `cannot read subscriber`. My desired result would it to echo `in my second directory`.

Comment: Do you have permissions, or better, does PHP have permission to read that directory. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: PHP does have permission on this directory to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of the second `opendir` is relative to the location of the script:

```
if($handle = opendir('subscribers/'.$entry)){
```

This fixed it for me.